# Doctrine2 OneToMany count

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entities: User and Comment.

In User have:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="User", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"sort_priority" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $Comments;
```

In my custom class I have query:

```
$query = 'SELECT u from BackendUserBundle:User u WHERE u.status != 0';
```

This query return all users but I want return user with count(Comments) >0. I cant use `Join` because I using `iterate()`.

Answer (score 1):

OK I found in Doctrine docs:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

> createQuery('SELECT u FROM CmsUser u WHERE
>   SIZE(u.phonenumbers) > 1'); $users = $query->getResult();